# Почему не работает pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Вот ошибка:

```
pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\danila\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
 File "c:\users\danila\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
 32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
 exec(code, run_globals)
 File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `pip install <somemodule>`

Comment: python -m pip install lib_name --user работает?

Comment: nick_gabpe, ошибки не выдаёт, но модуль не устанавливается

Comment: Попробуйте удалить все интерпретаторы python кроме одного. Похоже, что у вас установлены Python 3.4 и 3.7.

Comment: Из какой директории Вы запускаете? Пробовали из другой?